# Android Databinding view tag isn't correct on view:null

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

the question tag may be familiar in stackoverflow but I have some situation here. I want to achieve that my app will have a bottom menu bar which will be visible across the application. So I added a view and set it on my base activity Like following

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    fullLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);
    configureToolbar(fullLayout);
    subActivityContent = (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, subActivityContent, true);
    super.setContentView(fullLayout);
}
```

Previously it was like:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, null);
    configureToolbar(view);
    super.setContentView(view);
}
```

Now on some page there is data-binding. Which is called like following:

```
   viewModel = new MyViewModel(someId, someName, false, emptyString);
   binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_my_layout);
   binding.setItem(viewModel);
```

Now I am getting error on 2nd line.

Here is my activity layouts. 1st one is common layout which is activity_base, 2nd one is data binding Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include android:id="@+id/app_bar" layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs" />
```

2nd layout:

```
<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name="item"
        type="io.ppp.views.someActivity" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="io.ppp.views.someActivity">

    <include  android:id="@+id/app_bar"  layout="@layout/app_bar" />
    <!--<include  layout="@layout/activity_base" />-->




    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webViewLoader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="@{item.loading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/search_progress"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:indeterminate="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="@{item.loadingText}"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good solution to implement a bottom navigation bar across your application since you are creating Activities, and it will be clear to the user that every time you change activity the screen will totally swap (bottom bar included) instead of keeping a fixed element in the bottom of the screen which the user will use to guide himself across the application.

Implementing Bottom Navigation in Android is much trickier than it is in iOS since you are going to have to work with ONE SINGLE Activity and Fragments(Lots of them if you have a lot of screens) to achieve a smooth bottom navigation like application.

My advice to you is to transform your activities into fragments, implement the bottom navigation Activity with the bottom bar and a fragment container, and go from there.

From API 25 it was introduced the `BottomNavigationView` which will make your life easier and you won't need to use `BottomBar` library from GitHub. I also advice to look at `AHBottomNavigation`, it seems to me more complete than the native one, gives you a better control and choices over your bottom bar.

Comment: Hello, appreciated your comment.In my application bottom bar will only use for swapping between 2 pages and rest of the activities and navigation will work from upper portion. So the thing is, it is not like fully tab dependent application.

Comment: That is the problem, it is not a good practice to do it even for two single pages. You should have one single Activity, with a fragment container, and swap the view in the container

Comment: I know that but my superior introduce the bottom bar in the middle of the project and the project pattern is not build like the way it should. So if there is anyway that I can avoid the error it will be helpful.

Comment: I also had to implement the bottom navigation in the project I am running and my advice to you is to transform your activities into fragments, and implement the Bottom Navigation Activity thats handles all the swaps

Comment: Might take a while, but you will have a better solution at the end and one you can keep on going further in time